# How to launch own 2to3 fixer?

Tags: python, python-2to3

I wrote own fixer, how can i run it? I don't find obvious way to do this.

Only this:

```
> cd /usr/lib/python2.7/lib2to3/fixes/
> ln -s path/to/my_fixer.py
```

And then run it:

```
> cd path/to/project
> 2to3 -f my_fixer .
```

Comment: If you are not sure how to run it, you probably shouldn't be creating it.

Comment: But i need it! I'm looking for tool for global modifying source code with saving comments, 2to3 seems have appropriate functionality. If you know a answer why you didn't say it? :(

Comment: grep + awk + sed + xargs + 2to3?

Comment: awk/sed - good tools, but i need calculate some logic in Python.

Comment: Ok, what if you just teach your custom converter to operate on single file, get the filename to operate on from stdin, and then use grep/find/ln/whatever to get a list of files in a directory and than feed it to your converter through stdin?

Comment: Why i must use custom converter when have standard tool for that? Thanks for comments. But i have found the needed answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it! (file: my2to3)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import sys
from lib2to3.main import main

sys.path.append('path/to/my_own_package')
sys.exit(main('my_own_package.contained_fixers'))
```

And then run it:

```
> ./my2to3 -f my_fixer -w project
```

Answer (score 3):

- Create a directory `/mypath/custom_fixers`
- Generate a file `/mypath/custom_fixers/fix_custom_fixers.py` with this content:

  ```
  from lib2to3.fixer_base import BaseFix
  from lib2to3.pgen2 import token

  class FixCustomFixers(BaseFix):

      _accept_type = token.NAME

      def match(self, node):
          if node.value == 'oldname':
              return True
          return False

      def transform(self, node, results):
          node.value = 'newname'
          node.changed()
  ```
- Create a file `/mypath/myfixer.py` with this content:

  ```
  import sys
  from lib2to3.main import main
  sys.exit(main('custom_fixers'))
  ```
- Run `PYTHONPATH=/mypath python3 /mypath/myfixer.py -f custom_fixers python_file_to_fix.py`