# Add custom fixer to lib2to3 after fixer has been written

Tags: python, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, python-2to3

I am working on writing a custom fixer for [lib2to3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html), not to migrate code to Python 3, but to utilize the source code parsing functionality of lib2to3 rather than manually parsing source with regexs and the like.

I've written a basic fixer at this point, but I am not sure how to actually add this to lib2to3. I only want to use the single fixer, I do not intend to migrate any code to Python 3. This shouldn't be a problem as one can specify that only explicitly passed fixers be used:

`2to3 -f fixer_name.py example.py`

I could of course just add the fixer to the fixer path:

`lib2to3/fixes/`

but the script is intended to be distributed as a tool for users to migrate their old source code which uses deprecated import formats. Unfortunately, the documentation for lib2to3 is lacking and the [only writeup](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2010/2/11/porting-to-python-3-a-guide/) I have found suggests using the deprecated [distribute](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) package.

Any suggestions are welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question is answered here included below (basically replicating the 2to3 driver code and passing in your own package path):

[How to launch own 2to3 fixer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508357/how-to-launch-own-2to3-fixer)

my2to3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import sys
from lib2to3.main import main

sys.path.append('path/to/my_own_package')
sys.exit(main('my_own_package.contained_fixers'))
```

put fix_my_fixer.py in the package directory and run with

> ./my2to3 -f my_fixer -w project